# Why is the degree of this field extension $[K(x,y): K(x^p, y^p)]= p^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Fix a prime $p$. Let $K:=\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$.  Consider now the field $K(x,y)$ of rational functions in $x,y$ and its subfield $K(x^p,y^p)$ of rational functions in $x^p, y^p.$

According to Dummit & Foote (p.595), we have $[K(x,y): K(x^p, y^p)]= p^2$.

While I can intuitively see that this should be the case, I am not able to prove it. Could anyone suggest some good approaches?

Comment: Hint: $K(x^p, y^p)$ is the compositum of $K(x^p,y)$ and $K(x,y^p)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll rephrase slightly to try to make things clearer.

Let $L=\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}(z,w)$ where $z$ and $w$ are indeterminates.

The polynomial $\mathbf{X}^p-z\in L[\mathbf{X}]$ is irreducible over $L$. Therefore if $\alpha\in\overline{L}$ is a root of it, we have 
$$[L(\alpha):L]=\deg(\text{minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $L$})=p$$
Similarly the polynomial $\mathbf{X}^p-w\in L(\alpha)[\mathbf{X}]$ is irreducible over $L(\alpha)$, and if $\beta\in \overline{L}$ is a root of it,
$$[L(\alpha,\beta):L(\alpha)]=\deg(\text{minimal polynomial for $\beta$ over $L(\alpha)$})=p$$
Therefore
$$[L(\alpha,\beta):L]=[L(\alpha,\beta):L(\alpha)][L(\alpha):L]=p\cdot p=p^2$$
In this story, we just have
$$\alpha=x,\qquad \beta=y,\qquad z=x^p,\qquad w=y^p$$